# How to display an image just for a few seconds and close it?

Tags: shell, imagemagick

Is there an one line command that can display an image and then hold it on screen for a few seconds and then close it? I checked the display manual and no options there.

I would like to have something like:

```
display -density 200 -hold 3 myvector.eps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this dirty method? :

```
display -density 200 -hold 3 myvector.eps &
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -2 $pid
```

Comment: thanks a lot! With c shell, I am able to do the job with `display -density 200 Residuals.eps & && set pid=$! && sleep 3 && kill $pid`. Not sure what `-2` means in your kill command.

Comment: -2 => kill 'display' with SIGINT (same as ^C)... check `man 7 signal` for names of all signals...